What would happen if the sun became the size of the earth?
Imagine that a sudden force crushed the Sun from its current size down to the size of the earth,held it at that size for a few moments and then disappeared. What'd happen?
I haven't done any of the math but it feels like all the potential energy stored in the Sun would be sufficient to fuse  literally all of its mass to carbon atleast instantly (don't know about iron cause white dwarfs are already the mass of the sun and size of the earth), releasing all that energy as a (very unconventional) supernova as soon as the force disappears.
Would be nice if someone could try this scenario out.

Since your question is based on the existence of forces far beyond known physics, it is very difficult to answer it within the realm of known physics. The Worldbuilding SE (https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) might be a better home for this question.

@gandalf61 Is it really that far beyond current physics considering hypernovas and neutron stars exist and we know(assuming what we know is correct) how they work?

"...a sudden force crushed the Sun from its current size down to the size of the earth, held it at that size for a few moments and then disappeared..." - there is nothing remotely like this in known physics. The physics of supernovae and hypernovae is quite well understood and does not resemble this at all.

Actually, this is a good physics question. Those forces are irrelevant: what matters is the ideal gas law, thermodynamics, Fermi pressure and issues of degenerate matter.

Please ask only one main question per post, and try to make it more specific than "what would happen". Like one of the three questions.

The ideal gas law gives a first hint of trouble: if you compress gas by a factor of $(r_{sun}/r_{earth})^3\approx 100^3=10^6$, you should expect the temperature to go up by a factor of a million if done rapidly. This is not just enough to fuse hydrogen anywhere in the mass, but also produce a exotic particle reactions not normally seen outside neutron stars. You have what is essentially a white dwarf star at a billion degrees.
If you keep those mysterious forces going, it is mainly going to cool down via the Urca process: neutrons and protons react, producing copious amounts of neutrinos. In neutron stars this can radiate away about a solar luminosity per cubic meter, but here we have a factor of a billion less dense matter, so the rate will merely be enormous (since the entire bulk is radiating, not just the surface). The photon surface brightness will obviously be enormous: Stefan-Boltzmanns' law indicates that it will be $10^{27}$ times higher per square meter than on the Sun, but the surface area is 10,000 times smaller. still, you end up with something $10^{23}$ times brighter than the sun.
If you don't let go of the mysterious forces, the solar system evaporates due to this radiation. If you let go of the mysterious forces quickly, you get something like a supernova. I suspect it will not produce a dense remnant because everything is pretty isothermal and very, very hot. Maybe some remnants of the giant planets survive after having most of their atmosphere stripped, now ejected in interstellar space.
While mysterious forces can of course do anything, gas laws, nuclear physics, hydrostatic equilibrium, blackbody radiation etc. do give pretty firm answers even in extreme scenarios.

I think this is a good attempt at an answer - but an enormous force that suddenly appears and then disappears without cause is fundamentally unphysical. Is the force due to an massive concentration of matter or energy within the Sun ? Is this enough to create a black hole ? Or are we suspending relativity for the duration ? If we are going so far beyond physics as we know it then my hypothesis this event will turn the Sun into a cloud of fluffy pink unicorns.

Infinite frictionless planes are obviously unphysical - they should implode into black holes, after all. Yet mechanics would be pretty impossible if we always had to characterize material properties for every surface when we tried to explain basic dynamics. The third law of thermodynamics forbids zero temperature bodies, yet many papers use $T=0$. Idealizations can include distinctly unphysical assumptions as long as we don't let the irrelevant and arbitrary aspects of these assumptions determine the analysis.

@gandalf61 I still don't really get your point.
1)Why does it matter where the force is coming from? Its for the sake of the what if.It shouldn't change the outcome.
2) Considering white dwarfs with more mass than the sun exist,idk why this is even a question.And even if it were compressed to becoming a black hole,whats the problem?Look at what concept can apply,do the maths and see the result.Isnt that the fun in physics questions?
PS.I'm a high schooler so forgive me if there's like some limitations in higher level physics for such hypothetical scenarios.
